# find and highlight difference

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I know there are many questions asked on the same topic as I have here, they don't seem to solve my problem here. 
I have a task to compare two sheets (A and B) based on column D of both sheets and I want to find and highlight the rows in B that doesn't exist in A.
The code goes like this:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim data As Range
Dim ref As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Worksheets("B").UsedRange
Set ref = Worksheets("test").Columns("D:D").Value
lastRow = Worksheets("B").UsedRange.Rows.Count

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'     check if data exist in both shts
        For i = 10 To lastRow
            Set data = Worksheets("B").Columns("D:D").Find(ref,LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole)

            If data Is Nothing Then
                data.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
                Exit For
            Else
            End If
    Next
```

Now the problem is that the line that sets ref is having an error of object required, and the rows are not highlighted.

The screenupdating function is turned off for a shorter run time but it still take some time to run my code, is this the file's or the code's problem?

Advices would be very much appreciated.

**UPDATE** Task solved using the following code:

```
    With Worksheets("test")
    For i = 4 To lastRow
        For j = 4 To lastnewRow
            If Worksheets("test").Cells(i, 9) = Worksheets("B").Cells(j, 9) Then
              Exit For
            Else
                If j = lastnewRow Then
                    Worksheets("test").Cells(i,9).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
End With
```

Comment: You try to access a attribute of data only in the case data is nothing which doesnt make sense at all.

Comment: it is because I am trying to address the rows that only exist in Sheet B, is the code not right then?

Comment: I understand but this is just a part of my code. What I have to do is to check whether the list in sheet A has everything on the list in Sheet B, if not then highlight the rows that doesn't exist in sheet B and I will have to deal with that data later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Dim shtARng As Range, cell As Range

With Worksheets("A") '<--| change "A" with your actual sheet name
    Set shtARng = .Range("D1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp))) '<--| change "D1" to the column D actual initial row to start your check from
End With

With Worksheets("B") '<--| change "B" with your actual sheet name
    For Each cell in .Range("D1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp)))
        If shtARng.Find(What:=cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False) Is Nothing Then cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
    Next cell
End With
```

Comment: Thank you! The code solved the problem of highlight but it seems to be highlighting my entire excel table... any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not by my PC so you just place some breakpoints in your code and then step through it with F8, and see what's happening!

Comment: While stepping through code use the Immediate Window to inquiry variables values (for instance: "?shtARng.Address", "?cell.Address, cell.Value")

Comment: I think the problem is that when I set the range of shtRng it returns nothing to me thats why the whole sheet is highlighted, but why is that the case?

Comment: or would it be the value inside the cells that I am comparing are not "comparable" in excel? because it contains both letters and numbers and have - , () and / .

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this without VBA. The feature you will use in excel is called conditional formatting.

So if you want to highlight all cells in `Sheet 2` that are not in `Sheet 1` Column A, you can select the cells in `Sheet 1`, create a new rule in the conditional formatting window and select

"Use a formula to determine which cells to format"

Then you insert the following formula

```
=ISNA(MATCH(A1,Sheet1!A:A,0))
```

and under Format, select the style you want to apply to the cells that match this criteria.

- `MATCH` searches for the value in Cell `A1` (but also all other cells you have selected) and checks if they exist in array `Sheet1!A:A` which is the whole column A
- `#N/A` is returned if the value is not found, therefore we want the expression to be true. That is why we use the function `ISNA(expression)` which returns true in that case.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer:) I am  aware of this function but I am just trying to automate this process and because after the data is highlighted I would like to copy it to a third worksheet so if it could be done within the same module in vb editor that'd be great, but thx for answering ;)